# How to do Alfresco using Alfresco SDK3.0

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-maven

I am working in an IT Company and I need to learn Alfresco.

Using Apache CMIS I am able to do all operations like creating folders, creating documents, creating links to these, etc.

Now I need to do these operations using Alfresco's API. I did Google a lot and found it is possible using Alfresco SDK 3.0.

I have gone through the document but not able to get any complete example which has been done on Java api.

**Can someone post an end-to-end example in Java creating a folder using the Alfresco SDK?**

Comment: Why does it have to be with the Java API? Why not use the Alfresco Public REST API if CMIS won't work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bests tutorials are provided by Jeff Potts in his website ecmarchitect:  [Alfresco Developer Tutorial Series](https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series)

Personally, I learned using Alfresco SDK from these tutorials. The series uses a single business case as an example that covers many different technical aspects of Alfresco. Each tutorial takes you through hands-on customizations, step-by-step, and includes ready-to-build source code so you can follow along using your own local installation.

Also, you can take a look at Jeff Potts's book [Alfresco One 5.x Developer's Guide - Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1787128164)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading books or articles online.

You can also find examples in the automated tests.

You can find some at: [Alfresco Repository tests](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-repository/tree/master/src/test/java/org/alfresco)

There are many other automated tests where you can see how the Java APIs are used.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff Potts has some [great videos on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOEM5PcngNJV3weFgkCI6_yYdaYEPjQqc) showing how to do this. The example from [this series (*Public Alfresco API*)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOEM5PcngNJV3weFgkCI6_yYdaYEPjQqc) that most seems to fit what you're looking to learn is:

[Using the Alfresco API, Part 3: Creating Folders, Documents, Ratings, & Comments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZtmoPdCKJI)

Answer (score 0):

As Gagravarr suggests, I would recommend having a look here:

http://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/nodes/createNode

You will need to use something like: "nodeType": "cm:folder" but a folder is a node like any other.

Alfresco is starting to close the door on public APIs for the internal bits and pushing developers to start using the CMIS Rest API or the JavaScript API (though I think this may be deprecated soon as well).